# Flutter Web How to publish and host a site to other than a root folder

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Currently i was testing flutter web with default app template
i created a new project and build web target with

```
`flutter build web`
```

put all the files in subdirectory of local server, thus i can access them from

say http://127.0.0.1:43110/1ETE7PzFgfVdJ9YBhoG2uq1g5jwZ6N9Dou/

but i was not able to load the flutter app correctly.

i was getting the below errors

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:43110/assets/FontManifest.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Uncaught Failed to load asset at "assets/FontManifest.json" (0)
    at Object.a (http://127.0.0.1:43110/1ETE7PzFgfVdJ9YBhoG2uq1g5jwZ6N9Dou/main.dart.js:3657:3)
    at http://127.0.0.1:43110/1ETE7PzFgfVdJ9YBhoG2uq1g5jwZ6N9Dou/main.dart.js:15533:9
    at WK.a (http://127.0.0.1:43110/1ETE7PzFgfVdJ9YBhoG2uq1g5jwZ6N9Dou/main.dart.js:5208:72)
    at WK.$2 (http://127.0.0.1:43110/1ETE7PzFgfVdJ9YBhoG2uq1g5jwZ6N9Dou/main.dart.js:26450:23)
    at VZ.$2 (http://127.0.0.1:43110/1ETE7PzFgfVdJ9YBhoG2uq1g5jwZ6N9Dou/main.dart.js:26445:25)
    at UN.Sx (http://127.0.0.1:43110/1ETE7PzFgfVdJ9YBhoG2uq1g5jwZ6N9Dou/main.dart.js:27054:42)
    at UN.Sw (http://127.0.0.1:43110/1ETE7PzFgfVdJ9YBhoG2uq1g5jwZ6N9Dou/main.dart.js:27056:32)
    at fm.Qv (http://127.0.0.1:43110/1ETE7PzFgfVdJ9YBhoG2uq1g5jwZ6N9Dou/main.dart.js:26578:23)
    at Tl.$0 (http://127.0.0.1:43110/1ETE7PzFgfVdJ9YBhoG2uq1g5jwZ6N9Dou/main.dart.js:26725:36)
    at Object.n9 (http://127.0.0.1:43110/1ETE7PzFgfVdJ9YBhoG2uq1g5jwZ6N9Dou/main.dart.js:5324:76)
a @ main.dart.js:3657
$0 @ main.dart.js:27022
aec @ main.dart.js:5356
aen @ main.dart.js:5358
$1 @ main.dart.js:26383
af9 @ main.dart.js:3738
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:3746
childList (async)
$1 @ main.dart.js:26390
a42 @ main.dart.js:5363
nB @ main.dart.js:5420
lW @ main.dart.js:26656
d1 @ main.dart.js:26573
nb @ main.dart.js:26566
iB @ main.dart.js:26567
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:3781
$1 @ main.dart.js:29789
af9 @ main.dart.js:3738
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:3746
error (async)
Ii @ main.dart.js:29019
it @ main.dart.js:29015
uz @ main.dart.js:4897
yO @ main.dart.js:29783
b3 @ main.dart.js:7256
aae @ main.dart.js:7243
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:15510
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:5208
$2 @ main.dart.js:26450
a8 @ main.dart.js:5194
Rn @ main.dart.js:15542
ca @ main.dart.js:15504
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:22768
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:5208
$2 @ main.dart.js:26450
a8 @ main.dart.js:5194
S9 @ main.dart.js:22802
fe @ main.dart.js:22762
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:6968
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:5208
$2 @ main.dart.js:26450
a8 @ main.dart.js:5194
Gl @ main.dart.js:6970
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:6931
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:5208
$2 @ main.dart.js:26450
a8 @ main.dart.js:5194
nz @ main.dart.js:6942
afD @ main.dart.js:6919
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:13935
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:5208
$2 @ main.dart.js:26450
a8 @ main.dart.js:5194
Xj @ main.dart.js:13946
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:50140
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:50134
dartProgram @ main.dart.js:50137
(anonymous) @ main.dart.js:50140
Show 26 more frames
main.dart.js:7244 

GET http://127.0.0.1:43110/assets/FontManifest.json net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: Did you read the comment in `index.html` about setting base href when not hosted at / on your server?

Answer (score 1):

Update the `<base href="/">` tag in `web/index.html`

In your case: `<base href="/1ETE7PzFgfVdJ9YBhoG2uq1g5jwZ6N9Dou/">`

Answer (score 0):

you should comment this line  `<base href="/">` on `yourProjectDirectory/web/index.html`
. after that run `flutter build web` in terminal and then copy folder `yourProjectDirectory/build/web` on your any directory  that you want on server.  it will work at the your address in browser.